# Rewiring My Security Alarm Power Source

Tags: receptacle, security, alarm, rewire

A year or so ago when I got my security system installed, they drilled a whole in my wall under an outlet and mounted a permanent plug there.  I would like to reclaim this plug for both convenience and aesthetics.
[image: Outlet & Plug]
[image: Plug Close up]

I was thinking that I could just wire these into the wiring directly, but then I realized that this is a transformer, so that would not like work.  My next thought was to install an outlet on the opposite side of the wall in the garage.  Is there an easier/better/other option?

Comment: Who is the alarm Company who installed that? They should have used a slightly larger gauge two conductor cable not use a four conductor cable and splice them, they spliced two conductors together twice making it kind of like a two conductor cable because they knew the 22 gauge single conductors alone weren’t sufficient to carry the power, they should’ve just pulled an 18 or 16 gauge- 2 conductor cable. A wiring inspector would not approve of that installation. He did know enough to not have it on a GFI if it has fire alarm on the panel as well and reporting to a central station. In that scenar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add another outlet to the garage side but it will probably need to be offset from the current box. With the new outlet in the garage it will need to be a GFCI type outlet to meet code.
A [old work box](https://www.zoro.com/raco-electrical-box-switch-1-gang-509/i/G2797173/?gdffi=047ada998cf641fa93e55ae8579df863&gdfms=9BBEBCE29A674B35AFFF4A0C2A1244E8&gclid=CKOl34SGj8sCFYGFaQodpc0PgQ&gclsrc=aw.ds) would be the easiest to add.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I think I recall, he did not plug it in the garage because they are ground fault outlets.  They could trip and I would never know (at least that is what I remember).  So I guess I have a choice to make.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You made the right call by not connecting those low voltage wires directly to your high voltage wiring - bad things would happen, possibly including a fire.

The easiest solution to make the outlet usable (though not the most aesthetically pleasing) would be to screw in a [6 outlet adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009HKEXM), then plug the transformer into that adapter, that would give you 3 - 5 free plugs for your own use:

[image]

Or, keep the transformer in the lower outlet and use a 3 plug adapter in the top plug:

[image]

Or, just plug a power strip into the top outlet.

Comment: I suppose I should have been clear, aesthetics are my top reason for wanting to do this.  Getting the outlet back would be a nice bonus.